# Xiamen 10-hour layover questions

Tags: china, layovers, taiwan

I'm flying from Jakarta to Taiwan (TSA airport) with a 10+ hour layover in Xiamen with a US passport. I found out from YouTube that I can join a free city tour there. But there are some unanswered questions:

1. How's the paperwork like there? I've done similar thing before with other cities in China (Guangzhou and Chengdu), but before Covid. I assume I need to get a 24-hour visa? How long usually does it take to process now?
2. What to do with checked baggage?
3. Any other tips? Can't miss? Thanks.
4. Any thoughts on arriving on TSA vs TPE?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're eligible for 24-hour transit without a visa (TWOV). You just need to present your passport and Immigration form. Queuing up can take a while - it certainly did day before yesterday when we arrived in Xiamen, despite a foreigners-only line. But the inspection itself takes only a few minutes.

Your checked luggage will most probably be checked in all the way, so you won't see it until you arrive in Songshan.

About Songshan, it is in downtown Taipei, and while it is an old, slightly messy airport, you can't beat the location. Last time I landed there it took me about 15 minutes to reach the Hyatt, instead of 1.5 hours...

Xiamen is a beautiful city with lots of good food. Probably not the most accessible, language-wise, though. I don't do guided tours, and tend to explore on my own. The airport is on the northern side of the island. On the southwest side is Xiamen University, Zhongshan Pedestrian street and the ferry to Gulangyu island. This could fill the 7 hours or so you have out of a 10-hour layover.

Answer (score 3):

> How's the paperwork like there? I've done similar thing before with other cities in China (Guangzhou and Chengdu), but before Covid. I assume I need to get a 24-hour visa?

No need to prepare anything, you qualify to enter visa-free. https://www.xiamenair.com/brandnew_EN/passenger-service/transfer-ch.html  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20231224105609/https://www.xiamenair.com/brandnew_EN/passenger-service/transfer-ch.html)).